# Avira for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64.Bit

Tags: 14.04, antivirus

How i can install Avira Antivir for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64.Bit?

I am a beginner with Ubuntu, please explain it simply.

Comment: Avira discontinued their Linux support: https://www.avira.com/en/support-for-home-knowledgebase-detail/kbid/1491

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avira Free Antivirus 2015 is not available for Linux distributions. No new licenses are being granted for Avira Free Antivirus Linux, and the Avira Linux product will be terminated by June 30, 2016 for prior existing users. You're a beginner with Ubuntu, so you probably are not a prior existing user of Avira Free Antivirus Linux.

In its place you can install ClamTk from the Ubuntu Software Center. ClamTk is a GUI front-end for ClamAV, which is a command-line antivirus utility for Unix/Linux. Installing the ClamTk package will also install ClamAV and clamav-freshclam virus database update utility as dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You can install Avira Antivirus in Ubuntu but do you really need it? For What? You can read tutorial HowTo over [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus/Avira) you should read carefully what you be doing. More detailed information about antivirus for Ubuntu you can find [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus) including AviraAV.

Answer (score 0):

"Avira Antivirus 2015 is not available for Linux distributions"
Also, you won't really need an antivirus if you install software from trusted sources (Ubuntu store or ppas)
Enjoy your GNU/Linux distro!